# How do I decide if I should use a TServiceThread or TThread with my TService application?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, service

While reading some material (like [this one](http://www.tolderlund.eu/delphi/service/service.htm)) on how to create a service application that spawns a separate worker thread for each service request (because my service requests are likely to entail lengthy database operations), I've come across references to TThread and other references to TServiceThread. Now I'm confused. *Which one should I use? and Why?* and if you want to be super helpful and want to share your expertise on *how* or maybe you know of an *exceptionally great link* (emphasis on *quality* of content on the other side of that link) then that would contribute to the resolution of this asker's situation. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`TServiceThread` is the thread that implements the main service thread. It is intended solely for that purpose and you should not derive your work thread from `TServiceThread`. For a worker thread, derive from `TThread`.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.SvcMgr.TServiceThread) is perhaps a little hazy, but it does point in the right direction:

> TServiceThread represents the thread associated with a specific
>   service (TService object).
>
> TServiceThread is the thread associated with a service. Each service
>   application has one or more service objects, each of which has its own
>   dedicated thread. TServiceThread instances represent those threads.

And take a look at the implementation of  `TServiceThread.Execute`. It contains all the logic that is needed to implement a service's main thread. It is clearly not appropriate for a worker thread.

Comment: +1. Might I suggest you add emphasis to the sentence starting with "Each service application" (and maybe the one after it)? Those two seem to be the most relevant ones to the point. (The docs are a little hazy with the phrasing.)

Comment: +1 Thanks. I think they should replace their documentation with your first 2 sentences, and replace "service objects" with "instances of TService". I also don't understand why TServiceThread.Execute is not appropriate for a worker thread. I'm not asking for more info (your answer is already perfect), I'm just explaining why I didn't arrive at the same conclusion you did in the same way as you did. Obviously you have more experience, but a user shouldn't have to rely on their experience when reading documentation. That would be missing the point of documenation. Just sayin'. All good. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I think the documentation is very weak. In fact I'm not really sure why TServiceThread is even a public class.